Dynamic redirect url
I have a route like this
{
  path: 'entity/create/:id',
  component: EntityCreateComponent,
}

What I would like to do is, that the parent route redirects to the child by generating an id.
{
  path: `entity/create`,
  redirectTo: `entity/create/${generateNewId()}`,
}

This work in some way. The only problem I have is it uses the same id for all redirects, but I want the redirect to generate a new id every time it redirects.
For own app specific reasons I don't want to have the component, that redirects to entity\create, generating the id itself for the navigation.
I know I can create a guard or a dummy component for the parent route, but can it be done without?

The function will only run once, hence you are getting a single ID, the routing is not dynamic, since redirectTo only accepts string input.
One solution we can do is, create a dummy guard, that will serve as the ID generating middle man, for this scenario
Routing:
{
  path: `entity/create`,
  canActivate: [canActivateGenerateId],
}

Guard:
const canActivateGenerateId: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot,
) => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  const generateRandomId = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return router.createUrlTree(["entity/create/", generateRandomId()]);
};

